# Video displaying wrong aspect ratio on TV

Tags: video, aspect-ratio

I have a source video file for which mediainfo shows 1280*536 (2.40:1) for video stream. I run this in VLC and there are black bars on the top and bottom and when I change the aspect ratio within VLC to 16:9 it fills out all the screen and runs without black bars.

I now want to run this video from my native TV video player via USB without black bars (all screen filled in, my TV is a 32inch 16:9 TV)
I've tried running the below outputs on TV but even though all run at native 16:9 within VLC, every single one of them still runs as 2.40:1 on my TV (i.e with top and bottom black bars) -

1. Remuxing this mkv in MKVTOOLnix with setaspectratio as 16/9.
2. Remuxing this mkv in MKVTOOLnix with displayheight set as 720 instead of 536 to stretch it.
3. Converting this mkv to mp4 with HD video converter factory pro and setting aspect ratio as 16:9
4. Remuxing the converted mp4 with my mp4box gui with PAR set as 16:9 PAL

Can someone kindly suggest how shall I display play this video without black bars on my TV as my tv does not have a setting to change aspect ratio

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, i fixed it by calculating the exact PAR value and then setting it for my mp4 file using mp4box gui

PAR = DAR/SAR

where DAR is Display aspect ratio i.e 16/9 and 
SAR is storage aspect ratio i.e actual frame width and frame height of your mp4 video

So in my case i checked in video details to find frame width and frame height which was 1280*540
Then i calculated the PAR = (16/9)/(1280/540) = (16*540)/(1280*9) = 3/4

now i can see videos in my TV without the Black bars on top and bottom.